# sql join counts

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this statement which returns 2 different counts and i'm trying to join these counts about the month. Below is my current statement and i know my issue is the COUNT(SecondColl.*) as STRAFT for the 2nd table. Can i do something like this?

```
WITH cte as(
    SELECT * FROM K1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM K2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM K3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM K4
), FirstColl as (SELECT * FROM (Select DP, RN, ET, ED, DT, COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY DP, RN) AS your_count
            from cte) a WHERE your_count = 1 and ET = 'Complete' and DT = 'STR'
), SecondColl as (SELECT * FROM (Select DP, RN, ET, ED, DT, COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY DP, RN) AS your_count
            from cte) a WHERE your_count = 1 and ET = 'Complete' and DT = 'NCD'
)
SELECT MONTH(ED) as STRMnth, COUNT(*) as STRRFT , COUNT(SecondColl.*) as STRAFT
FROM FirstColl
inner join SecondColl where MONTH(ED) = SecondColl.MONTH(ED)
group by MONTH(ED)
order by STRMnth asc
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text. (I.e. no images.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH cte as(
    SELECT * FROM K1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM K2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM K3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM K4
), FirstColl as (SELECT * FROM (Select DP, RN, ET, ED, DT, COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY DP, RN) AS your_count
            from cte) a WHERE your_count = 1 and ET = 'Complete' and DT = 'STR'
), SecondColl as (SELECT * FROM (Select DP, RN, ET, ED, DT, COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY DP, RN) AS your_count
            from cte) a WHERE your_count = 1 and ET = 'Complete' and DT = 'NCD'
)
select 
    a.STRMnth, a.cnt1 as STRRFT, b.cnt2 as STRAFT
from 
    (select month(ED) as STRMnth, count(*) as cnt1 from FirstColl group by month(ED)) a
    left join 
    (select month(ED) as STRMnth, count(*) as cnt2 from SecondColl group by month(ED)) b
        on a.STRMnth = b.STRMnth
order by a.STRMnth asc
```

**UPDATE1:**

```
WITH cte as(
        SELECT * FROM K1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM K2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM K3
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM K4
    ), FirstColl as (SELECT * FROM (Select DP, RN, ET, ED, DT, COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY DP, RN) AS your_count
                from cte) a WHERE your_count = 1 and ET = 'Complete' and DT = 'STR'
    ), SecondColl as (SELECT * FROM (Select DP, RN, ET, ED, DT, COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY DP, RN) AS your_count
                from cte) a WHERE your_count = 1 and ET = 'Complete' and DT = 'NCD'
    ), ThirdColl as (SELECT Distinct ED, DP, RN FROM cte WHERE DT = 'STR')
    select 
        a.STRMnth, a.cnt1 as STRRFT, b.cnt2 as STRAFT
    from 
        (select month(ED) as STRMnth, count(*) as cnt1 from FirstColl group by month(ED)) a
        left join 
        (select month(ED) as STRMnth, count(*) as cnt2 from SecondColl group by month(ED)) b
            on a.STRMnth = b.STRMnth
        left join 
        (select month(ED) as STRMnth, count(*) as cnt3 from ThirdColl group by month(ED)) c
            on a.STRMnth = c.STRMnth
    order by a.STRMnth asc
```

**UPDATE2:**

```
WITH cte as(
        SELECT * FROM K1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM K2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM K3
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM K4
    ), FirstColl as (SELECT * FROM (Select DP, RN, ET, ED, DT, COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY DP, RN) AS your_count
                from cte) a WHERE your_count = 1 and ET = 'Complete' and DT = 'STR'
    ), SecondColl as (SELECT * FROM (Select DP, RN, ET, ED, DT, COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY DP, RN) AS your_count
                from cte) a WHERE your_count = 1 and ET = 'Complete' and DT = 'NCD'
    ), ThirdColl as (SELECT distinct ED, DP, RN FROM K1 WHERE Defect_Type = 'STR')
    select 
        a.STRMnth, a.cnt1 as STRRFT, b.cnt2 as STRAFT
    from 
        (select month(ED) as STRMnth, count(*) as cnt1 from FirstColl group by month(ED)) a
        left join 
        (select month(ED) as STRMnth, count(*) as cnt2 from SecondColl group by month(ED)) b
            on a.STRMnth = b.STRMnth
        left join 
        (select month(ED) as STRMnth, count(*) as cnt3 from ThirdColl group by month(ED)) c
            on a.STRMnth = c.STRMnth
    order by a.STRMnth asc
```

Comment: i get an error with this due to the ED not being in the agg function

Comment: I'm trying to add an additional column to this statement with a Select Distinct, Are you able to point me in the right direction with this?  This is what i am trying STRTotalColl as (SELECT Distinct DP, RN  FROM cte
   WHERE DT = 'STR' 
)

Comment: What do you want to show? Now you have aggregate table with month and two counts of records in your FirstColl and SecondColl tables grouped by month. Do you trying to add a third count column?

Comment: Yes correct im trying to add another column selecting distinct results and grouping about the month.

Comment: What is the problem with using third CTE table in your query? Check my update. Hope it will help you.

Comment: So the problem is i can't have the ED in the Distinct Select as i'm trying to count the Distinct DP, RN only then bring the ED in later to help group the month they are in. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: So for all months it will be the same value?

Comment: I only want the count of DP & RN together in each month. This is my current code for doing so for one month but i was hoping to incorporate this into your example. SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT distinct DP, RN FROM K1 WHERE Defect_Type = 'STR' and Month(ED) = '08') as x